# Make expression that can handle large bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

Like many others I have the anoying VM budget problem. I am getting files from the sdcard and I decode it and comprimizes them using:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
```

The problem is that i get the bitmap each time i call the onCreate method. So after turning phone or starting the activity a couple of times it crashes. The only method I can find to avoid this is:`yourBitmap.recycle()`, but you can not catch a recycled Bitmap.

I need an expression that still manage to show the the bitmap even after it would normaly crashed on VM budget. I am showing the bitmap as a drawable, so the classic unbindDrawables solotion does not work. I need an expression that eighter comprimices the Bitmap to almost nothing, or that recycles and shows a new Bitmap of the same size.

Comment: It crashes... because of lack of memory?

Comment: How can I find out if my application is leaking memory?

Comment: I'm asking you... why does it crash? It's not even clear that memory is the issue.

Comment: It crashes because the app request more memory than it is allowed to use. Therefor it crashes on VM budget.

Answer (score 0):

try reading this:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

and watching this:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html

also , about drawables, see that you don't have any references to them after they are not needed . drawables can cause memory leaks.